# Optimization of date subtraction on large dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I'm a beginner learning Python. I have a very large dataset - I'm having trouble optimizing my code to make this run faster.

My goal is to optimize all of this (my current code works but slow):

1. Subtract two date columns
2. Create new column with the result of that subtraction
3. Remove original two columns
4. Do all of this in a fast manner

Random finds:
Thinking about changing the initial file read method...
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/fastest-python-library-to-read-a-csv-file

I have parse_dates=True when reading the CSV file - so could this be a slowdown? I have 50+ columns but only 1 timestamp column and 1 year column.

This column:

```
          saledate
1          3/26/2004 0:00
2          2/26/2004 0:00
3          5/19/2011 0:00
4          7/23/2009 0:00
5         12/18/2008 0:00
```

Subtracted by (Should this be converted to a format like 1/1/1996?):

```
          YearMade
1         1996
2         2001
3         2001
4         2007
5         2004
```

Current code:

```
mean_YearMade = dfx[dfx['YearMade'] > 1000]['YearMade'].mean()

def age_at_sale(df, mean_YearMade):
    '''
    INPUT: Dateframe
    OUTPUT: Dataframe
    Add a column called AgeSale
    '''
    df.loc[:, 'YearMade'][df['YearMade'] == 1000] = mean_YearMade
    # Column has tons of erroneous years with 1000
    df['saledate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['saledate'])
    df['saleyear'] = df['saledate'].dt.year
    df['Age_at_Sale'] = df['saleyear'] - df['YearMade']
    df = df.drop('saledate', axis=1)
    df = df.drop('YearMade', axis=1)
    df = df.drop('saleyear', axis=1)
    return df
```

Any optimization tricks would be much appreciated...

Comment: If you only care about the year and maximum efficiency, it would be faster to read in year made and year sold as integers and avoid datetime, but generally speaking it's better to carry datetimes as proper pandas datetimes.  But it's hard to generalize too much about efficiency here without sample data to test on.

Comment: The saledate and YearMade is the actual data - think of that but plus 500,000 rows of that. What do you mean by year made and year sold as integers? Are you saying I should convert saledate first as a string string, loop through each rough/cut out everything except year, then turn it into int's...then subtract by the other column which is in the normal year format (1995...etc.)?

Comment: Basically yeah.  Ideally just read in the 4 year columns as an integer and save all the datetime overhead.  But that's really just if you are reading in this CSV multiple times.  If you are reading in one time and then storing as HDF or whatever, then it probably makes sense to just store as datetime (although storing the year itself as an integer may still improve speed, I'm not sure how much tho).  This all really just depends on your specific case and only you can decide the best way.

Comment: @JohnE converting everything to HDF...was actually the thing that helped me the most. are there any downsides to HDF? i should have just started by converting everything to HDF and then playing around with everything...!

Comment: ;-)  CSV is more universal if you want to transfer data to other programs, but other than that, no real reason to use CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) for substract and for select by condition use `loc` with `mask` like `dfx['YearMade'] > 1000`. Also creating column `saleyear` is not necessary.

```
dfx['saledate'] = pd.to_datetime(dfx['saledate'])
mean_YearMade = dfx.loc[dfx['YearMade'] > 1000, 'YearMade'].mean()

def age_at_sale(df, mean_YearMade):
    '''
    INPUT: Dateframe
    OUTPUT: Dataframe
    Add a column called AgeSale
    '''
    df.loc[df['YearMade'] == 1000, 'YearMade'] = mean_YearMade
    df['Age_at_Sale'] = df['saledate'].dt.year.sub(df['YearMade'])
    df = df.drop(['saledate', 'YearMade'], axis=1)
    return df
```

Comment: Should I keep parse date on or off?

Comment: if use `parse_dates=True` it means you need datetimeindex. so try change it to `parse_dates=[position_of_column_with_dates]` - e.g. `parse_dates=[3]` (fourth column, because python count from `0`). But I ma not sure if `pd.to_datetime` or `parse_dates` is faster.

Comment: Just tested with parse_dates = [6,9] which is location of year made and sale date. This is purely the time to parse date, nothing else.

[Finished in 111.0s]

Will try pd.to_datetime now...